# Incremental ARM template deployment overwriting resources in Key vault access policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add AAD app in Key vault Access Policy.
AAD app gets added successfully, but it overrides the existing resources in Access Policy.

Deployment Mode is set as Incremental, but still facing this issue.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have posted an answer to a very similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261434/174843 ; I hope the answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

It overwrites the access policy array always, so make sure to include all of the users/groups/apps you want in the ARM template itself, and do not modify access policies from the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Setting AccessPolicy always overrides the existing policies...

But you can add an entry to the AccessPolicy in ARM; see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-keyvault-add-access-policy/azuredeploy.json

Also there is a workaround by first reading the existing policies and then add the one you need. 
See also: https://toonvanhoutte.wordpress.com/2018/11/13/key-vault-deployment-removes-access-policies/
Also there is a feature request, that AccessPolicy should also support incremental updates: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/34414747-arm-template-for-keyvault-to-have-accesspolicies-n

Comment: The feature request's URL is now dead. There is a new feature request here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/3f9f371f-f624-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 but the response from MS is to switch to RBAC instead.