# ARM Template - Keyvault - how to retain accesspolicies that are manually added

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a ARM template that I use to create a keyvault.

For a very specific reason, I need to manually set access policies on my keyvault once it's created.

If I run my ARM template again (to change some settings), the access policies I manually set are deleted.

What function or trick can I use to have an ARM template that combines access policies in the ARM template with the access policies that were set manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible; if you are using access policies, then you **must** specify them as you deploy the Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults resource.

The [ARM reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#vaultproperties) says

> access policies are required

---

There is a workaround, but it is not simple. Instead of using [access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-powershell), you need to use the [RBAC model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azurepowershell) to define access to your key vault.
That is what is recommended by Microsoft in response to a feature request [ARM Template for KeyVault to have AccessPolicies non-mandatory](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/3f9f371f-f624-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0):

> For anyone who opens this feedback item:
>
> - Use RBAC permission model: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the RBAC option as well. Nevertheless, I run into the same problem and I solved it by using PowerShell:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/new-azkeyvault?view=azps-10.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultaccesspolicy?view=azps-10.0.0